# How to schedule execution of Selenium web driver Script in midnight through windows scheduler or else?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Keyword driven framework designed using selenium webdriver. I have created a testsuite for all the test. I want to execute testsuite in midnight or at any time through scheduler(Windows). is there is way to do this? please give me the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate you selenium webdriver tests with Jenkins and schedule jenkins job according to your requirements.

https://jenkins-ci.org